# Android define SharedPreferences as far as global

Tags: android

in my application i want to set username and password from login with if user checked `CheckBox` to save remember that i want to use those in all of activity and i need to get simply that. now if i define `SharedPreferences` such as :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

can i access as far as global in all activities ?

Comment: hopefully I am not gonna download your app. Don't save a password in SharedPreferences!

Comment: @jan1337z `username` and `password` is sample of my ask fields sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be available to all Activities within your app package, as long as they all use the same 'name' parameter (`com.example.app`).